# How to access derived constructor in Meyers singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

My code:

```
template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& instance() {
        static T obj;
        return obj;
    }

protected:
    Singleton() { }
    Singleton(Singleton const& other);
    void operator=(Singleton const& other);
};

class Derived : public Singleton<Derived> {
protected:
    Derived() { }
};

void test() {
    Derived::instance();
}
```

I'm getting this error at the `static T obj` line:

```
‘Derived::Derived()’ is protected  
     Derived() { }
     ^
```

How do I fix this? Maybe using the `friend` keyword? But that'd be a bit awkward.

**Note:** The reason I'm aware of the name and idea of the Meyers singleton, but am implementing it by myself, is that I can't find where I first read about it. I thought it was either in "Effective C++" or in "More Effective C++", but I can't find it there. And the examples I find on the net don't use the CRTP-generalization.

Comment: The singleton pattern has been abandoned by its own creators later on. You should probably avoid using it. Meyers is not one of the authors.

Comment: This is indeed not the best idea. Just whatch this 5 minute video from CppCon2016 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23xDn3ReH7E), it is funny and instructive! (namespace are singleton [extensible])

Answer (score 1):

Make `Singleton` `instance` function member a friend of `Derived`:

```
struct Derived{
  //...
  friend Derived& Singleton<Derived>::instance();
  };
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `public Singleton<Derived> {
  friend class Singleton<Derived>; ....`